# Android seekbar value change button

Tags: java, android, seekbar

**project's problem Image:**

[image: project's problem Image]

Hi.
I want to know about this problem with these two buttons.
First of all, I emphasized two buttons. Left button is Decrease button and right button is Increase button.
And the problem is... 
If all values are the maximum value. Clicking the Increase button does not change the value. 
However, if I click the increase button two or three times and then click the decrease button to decrease the value again, the value does not change. To decrease the value, I must press the decrease button as much as I press the increase button. :(

When I first encountered this problem, I thought it was caused by the overlapping call of *OnClickListener*.
So I tried to avoid calling in duplicate if the value was the maximum, but I couldn't solve the problem. I ask questions because I've been looking for people who have had the same problem with me for about a week but haven't found a solution.
Please. I want to go home.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: as Karan Mehta said please share your code. if you can't try to use Live data for progress bar value and with simple if the condition you can check when you pressed increase button value if equal to max value ignore action and same thing for decrease button and value is equal to min.

Comment: I'm so sorry about the code. But the company's security policy does not allow us to post the code. Of course I know this is ridiculous, but I can't.. If you don't mind, could you share with me a document on this part or an appropriate search method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Kotlin

Your logic should be like this for increaseButton

```
        increaseButton.setOnClickListener {
        if(seekBar.progress > MAX_LIMIT) {
            seekBar.progress = MAX_LIMIT
            return@setOnClickListener
        }
        if (seekBar.progress == MAX_LIMIT) {
            // you can show notification that you are reach limit
            return@setOnClickListener
        }
        seekBar.progress = seekBar.progress + 1
    }
```

And same logic for decreaseButton

```
        decreaseButton.setOnClickListener {
        if(seekBar.progress < MIN_LIMIT) {
            seekBar.progress = MIN_LIMIT
            return@setOnClickListener
        }
        if (seekBar.progress == MIN_LIMIT) {
            // you can show notification that you are reach limit
            return@setOnClickListener
        }
        seekBar.progress = seekBar.progress - 1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code for updating the seek bar on button click.

```
SeekBar simpleSeekBar= new SeekBar(this);

        // Increase button Click {100 is the max value of SeekBar }
        if (simpleSeekBar.getMax() == 100){
            simpleSeekBar.setProgress(simpleSeekBar.getProgress() + 10);
        }

        //  Decrease button
        if (simpleSeekBar.getMax() <= 0){
            simpleSeekBar.setProgress(simpleSeekBar.getProgress() - 10);
        }
```

I hope it's helpful to you.